# Div's are over lapping?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a menu box and video box but my video box is overlapping the menu div's here is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
```

```html
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    .colm-1
    {
     float:left;
     display:block;
    }
    .my-video-box
    {
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background:#F00;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!--- My Menu Box --->
    <div class="colm-1">Colm 1</div>
    <div class="colm-1">Colm 1</div>
    <div class="colm-1">Colm 1</div>
    
    
    <!--- Video Box --->
    <div class="my-video-box"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my menu div's are floating left while i'm not floating my video div/box.

Comment: Maybe you can use position:relative; in the css classes to avoid overlapping?

Comment: should i use that with video box?

Comment: @ShekharPanjak what a edit...

Comment: thanks @shekharpankaj for helping :)

Comment: @WaseemKhan, remember whenever you are using float, don't forget to use clear as float will create empty space and clear:both will remove that space..better use inline-block rather then float

Comment: thanks @Leothelion it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use float in div's try to use clear after that try this

```
<body>
<!--- My Menu Box --->
<div class="colm-1">Colm 1</div>
<div class="colm-1">Colm 1</div>
<div class="colm-1">Colm 1</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div> <!-- You need to add this -->

<!--- Video Box --->
<div class="my-video-box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm glad to help, please accept my answer if it solve your problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write this html before `my-video-box` div.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```